# Pinching zoom a custom UIView: lines and text are pixelate, needs to be re-rasterized

Tags: ios, uiview, pinchzoom

I have a custom UIView. In this view I am overriding drawRect to draw some paths and some text. 
When a tap is detected, the view is zooming in

```
 - (void)tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
     float zoom = 3.;
     sender.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sender.view.transform, zoom, zoom);
     ...
 }
```

Zoom works OK, but lines and text become pixelate as I zoom in. I want the lines width and the text size to stay the same, i.e. to be re-rasterized, so I insert a setNeedsDisplay at the end of the above method, but this has no effect, don't works.

Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `contentScale` of the layer in question.  This has worked for my paths.

Comment: Which layer? I do not think I have layer.

Comment: Every view has a layer...Without it you can't display things.  `view.layer`

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems with my map viewer, so i cooked up an isolated demo project. I got very heavy antialiasing when zoomed in. Basically, to rerasterize when zooming in, you have to play with the `rasterizationScale` like so:

```
    sublayer.rasterizationScale = scale;
    sublayer.contentsScale = scale;
```

Sample project and readme are here: https://bitbucket.org/robvanderveer/scrollviewdemo